# MongoDB : regex for a specific element in an array

Tags: arrays, regex, mongodb

Let say we have a collection structured like this:

```
{
  _id:1,
  tag:["speaker","tom"]
},
{
  _id:2,
  tag:["subject","tomatoes"]
}
{
  _id:3,
  tag:["subject","space"]
}
```

I can query for specific elements, such as :

```
db.tags.find({tag:["speaker","tom"]})
```

Now is it possible to perform a query with a regex matching the **second** element of that array ?
something like :

```
db.tags.find({tag:["speaker",/tom.*/]}) ?
```

A regex on the field `tag` (ie : `db.tags.find({tag:/sp.*/})`) would match the entire array, and I'm looking for a way to make it search only on the second one... before considering to have to restructure that collection.

**Update**

A workaround is to use the `$all` operator :

```
db.tags.find({tag:{$all : ["speaker",/tom.*/]} })
```

which is equivalent to :

```
db.tags.find({ $and: [ { tag: "speaker }, { tags: /tom.*/ } ] }
```

However, that's not the correct way to do, since both element are scanned for both the string and the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to redeem myself. I found you can do it this way using the aggregation framework

```
db.tags.aggregate([
    {$match: {"tag.1" : {$exists: 1}}},
    {$project: {one: {$slice: ["$tag", 1]}, two: {$slice: ["$tag", 1,2]}}},
    {$match: {one: "speaker", two: /tom.*/}}
])
```

first part make sure the array has atleast 2 elements. the project the first element onto `one` and the second element onto `two` using slice then match against the single element in each array now.

You can then either get the ID and go back to the original collection and run another query or add some more projections to this and extract the necessary data from the aggregation framework.

Comment: Yea Sorry. I assumed since this query works db.tags.find({"tag.1": {$exists: 1}}) that you'd be able to do something similar with a find but that does not seem to be the case.